# Can't start Seamless Mode despite installing Guest Additions

Tags: macos, virtualbox, debian

I've installed the guest additions on my Debian Linux virtual machine. Installation went through without any problems.

For some reason I still can't get the option to run in seamless mode (it's greyed out). VirtualBox is running on Mac OSX.

Answer (score 5):

Solved my problem. Make sure `dkms` is installed in the guest OS (following command for Debian Linux):

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r` dkms
```

Then re-install Guest Additions.

Comment: Not a biggie, but I thought I'd mention that I did have to restart the Guest after following these steps.